# Power BI Deskop calculated column very slow! help fix code

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I added a calculated column to get month of current years values. However, it is very slow! I have million rows and it takes like 180 seconds to generate! What's wrong with the below and is there a way to make it faster?

Please note I am using direct query to SQL tables and using Power BI Desktop

`January-CY = if('__Sales'[Month]=1 && '__Sales'[Year]=year(NOW()),'__Sales'[QTY])`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Direct Query is going to be slow without a doubt for a million rows, the real power of DAX comes when the data is in Import mode. Consider computing this field in the database itself.